# change different inputs values on one select

Tags: jquery

I want to get different input values on one select - option.
Only i cant make it work..

```
$("#theSelect").change(function() {
    if($("#theSelect") == "foo")    {
      someInput1.show();
      someInput1.value = "Some Foo text";

      someInput2.show();
      someInput2.value = "different Text";
    }
```

Anyone a idea?

See : 
http://jsfiddle.net/853GJ/2/

Comment: You have to compare the value of the select, not the jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I noticed within your jquery:

**jQuery**:

```
var $someInput1 =  $("#someInput1");
var $someInput2 =  $("#someInput2");

$someInput1.hide();
$someInput2.hide();

$("#theSelect").change(function() {  

    if($("#theSelect").val() === "foo"){
      $someInput1.show().val("Some Foo text");
      $someInput2.show().val("different Text");
    }

    if($("#theSelect").val() === "bar")    {
      $someInput1.show().val("Some bar text");
      $someInput2.show().val("Text....");
    }

}).change(); // trigger once if needed
```

- `if($("#theSelect") == 'foo'` was changed to `if($("#theSelect").val() == 'foo'`
- `.value` changed to `val()`
- Created cached variables for `$("#someInput1")` and `$("#someInput2")`.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/853GJ/9/)**

Comment: caching a selector like `someInput` that is being reused several times is far more efficient than what you are doing

Comment: I completely agree, but as written there were no variables containing those values. I'll go back and add them to be that way though.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the jquery `object` to a `string` value:

```
if($("#theSelect") == "foo")
```

You need to get the value using `.val()`:

```
if($("#theSelect").val() == "foo")
```

Also, you need to get the jquery object for the hidden inputs:

```
var someInput1 = $('#someInput1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get value of select element use `val` method for that. Also you may use `this` inside your `if` to get value of current element. Also you need to find your input elements to show them and to change its values.

```
$("#theSelect").change(function() {
  if($(this).val() == "foo") {
    $("#someInput1").show();
    $("#someInput1").val("Some Foo text");

    $("#someInput2").show();
    $("#someInput2").val("different Text");      
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the change handler `this` refers to the element.

In your if, you want to compare the `value` to the string which can be retrieved using `val()` method

```
$("#theSelect").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "foo")    {
     /* assuming that "someInput" is a jQuery object since you are using "show()"*/
        /* use val() since someINput is jQuery object... can chain the methods*/

      someInput1.show().val("Some Foo text"); 

    }
})
```